# Top Slide Menu Issue

Tags: javascript

I used a Codrops tutorial to recreate this menu. Now, I want it to slide from top (as it does) but the problem is that in this case it covers my 'menu' button so I cannot slide it back and hide it.

As I am not good with JavaScript I wanted to ask someone how to do this? I believe there is only a line or two of code that needs to be changed at the bottom script of HTML code.

Can anyone help me to fix this? All I am looking for is that when a user clicks on a white space below the menu, menu hids back. That would be awesome!

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yqszh/

```
<script>
        var menuTop = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s3' ),
            showTop = document.getElementById( 'showTop' ),
            body = document.body;

        showTop.onclick = function() {
            classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
            classie.toggle( menuTop, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
            disableOther( 'showTop' );
        };

        function disableOther( button ) {
            if( button !== 'showTop' ) {
                classie.toggle( showTop, 'disabled' );
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: There are two possibilities: 1) you need to slide the button with menu, so that it don't get covered by the menu or 2) provide a close button in the menu and hide the menu on its click.

Comment: Thanks. How can I provide a close button in the menu? With JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your `JSFIDDLE`, you can add the close button like this, you can style it as per your requirement.

JSFIDDLE Link : http://jsfiddle.net/Yqszh/1/

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Is this: <burron id="close" onclick="hideMenu();">X</button> the only part you added?

Comment: Ok. I did it this way and it works: <h3 onclick="hideMenu();">Menu</h3> Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Hmmm... It actually works in JSFiddle but not when I do the same change in my HTML. How come?